# Are we evolving as fast as the oxygen is depleting?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, physiology, adaptation

How much oxygen saturation have we lost in the last 100 years? As oxygen levels dwindle and industry, deforestation,  and population increases, at what year and saturation will the low levels of oxygen become a problem in human development? Would living or sleeping with higher levels of oxygen increase cognitive or physical ability?

Comment: Athletes in aerobic sports, e.g., cycling, sometimes live and sleep at lower (rather than higher) levels of oxygen in order to increase their oxygen carrying capacity and improve their physical performance. Particularly high levels of oxygen are actually toxic over moderate time periods.  I'm not sure either of these things are what you're getting at, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good estimates from ice core samples put the decrease in oxygen concentration at [0.7% over the last 800,000 years](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/353/6306/1427). At sea level, currently, inspired $P_{O2}$ is (760 mm Hg - 47) * 0.21, approximately 150mm Hg. Human physiology easily adapts to lower $P_{O2}$ levels, with approximately 140 million people living at elevations over 2500 m, with inspired $P_{O2}$ at 108mm Hg, and many permanent human settlements higher than 5000 m, with inspired $P_{O2}$ approximately half what it is at sea level (see West Respiratory Physiology, Ch. 9). A 0.7% decline over 800,000 years isn't going to be much of a challenge.

Comment: That is before we had chain saws. I'm looking for more recent numbers and the effects on the human body.+1 for the info though.

Comment: @Muze the impact of industry is an increase in certain gases, not a significant decrease in oxygen. The gases that have increased substantially since the industrial revolution, e.g., $CO_2$, $O_3$, $CH_4$ are low percentage gases, but have a significant effect on the temperature of the earth through their interaction with radiant energy. There isn't a significant $O_2$ depleting impact.

Comment: So there is a decrease although insignificant. It takes 10 trees to provide enough oxygen for 1 person and if those trees are cut exponentially oxygen supply will also continue to fall. yes?

Comment: @Muze Deforestation causes a $CO_2$ problem, not an $O_2$ problem. As you can see from my answer, we have a large excess of $O_2$. $CO_2$, however, is a greenhouse gas, and small absolute increases (which are large relative increases) have significant effects on the biosphere.

Comment: @Muze Claims like `It takes 10 trees to provide enough oxygen for 1 person` would really need a reference. You will note that, if I am not mistaken, while forests are good carbon store, many forest ecosystems do no capture more CO$_2$ than they produce as they've reached their [community climax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climax_community) and hence not [carbon sink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_sink#Forests). I would think that such statistics (`10 trees to provide enough oxygen for 1 person`) hide a much more complex reality and can only be misleading.

Comment: @Remi.b reference:  https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26823/18879

Comment: @Muze Your reference is a post of yours who itself refers to two posts of yours (one being downvoted and closed)! None of the link support the claim anyway and if they try to do so, they fail to consider the fact that, in an ecosystem, tree die and release the carbon they have accumulated during their lifetime.

Comment: @Remi.b some trees can live 100s to 1000s of years old and the carbon is not released in the atmosphere. Not arguing but I did get 200 bonus rep for that link.

Comment: Sure but, IMHO, whether they live 1000 years or 2 years, does not change anything that in ecosystems where trees die and others grow up is a carbon storage but not a carbon sink. Anyway... let's no chat further. I have opened the post [Does an old growth forest ecosystem produce more oxygen than it consumes?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/76650/does-an-old-growth-forest-ecosystem-produce-more-oxygen-than-it-consumes) to tackle the question.

Comment: @Muze a SE link is not a reliable source to back up a claim on a SE site, no matter how many votes or what bonus rep it has. The original references should be both independent and authoritative or else you run into citogenesis problems :)

Comment: Re "10 trees", you're forgetting about the oceans.